# Keeping URL of website unchanged while navigating in between sections of the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website is a single page website, the content is divided in sections. The navigation between these sections is done by a list as follows:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#Zero"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#One"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#Two"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#Three"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#Four"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want the URL for the website to remain unchanged, and not append the anchors #One, #two and so on to the URL while navigating to each of the sections.

I understand that the anchor is getting appended because of use of the `<a href="#">` tag. Is there an alternative way in either html or jquery or javascript to navigate between the sections so that the URL doesn't change?

I use dot-style navigation to navigate to sections and transition is fade-in fade-out style transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to each anchor that [hides](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) sections and [shows](http://api.jquery.com/show/) different ones.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firstLink').click(function() {
        // hide and show
        return false; // cancel the href navigation
    });
});
```

One advantage to actually changing the URL is that it allows the user to refresh the page without losing his/her current position. If you keep the URL the same and your users refresh, they go back to the default page.

Comment: I am not very good at jquery/javascript and have been searching for a sample code/example that can help me write the code in my case. Can you please share an example (if any) that uses your suggestion above? Also, I want to keep the URL the same, since I wish to redirect the user to homepage on refresh, rather than being on the same section.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one. I couldn't see the example code all this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery to do so.http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/ ScrollTo will do the same for you without changing the URL. On the click of the link.

Comment: Thanks. The transition for the sections is fade-in fade-out and I am using a dot-style navigation and hence the list.The above solution may not work in this case, right?